# counter with 3 signal

Tags: verilog, fpga

i want to create 3 signal in clock logic.

```
8s
7s ----- create working signal
6s
5s
4s
3s
2s
1s ----- create timeout signal
0s ----- create finish signal

always @(posedge CLK_1K or posedge signal_count) begin
    slot_count = 0;
    data_finish = 0;
    timeout = 0;
    working = 0;
    if (signal_count) begin
        slot_count <= 1;
        counter <= 8;
    end else if (counter > 0) begin
        counter = counter - 1;
        if (counter == 7) begin
            working = 1;
        end else if (counter == 1) begin
            timeout = 1;
        end else if(counter == 0) begin
            data_finish = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

> What had done:
>
> - test in simulator is normal.
> - download to Device not work...

what should i do next ? Thank you ....

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is your code working in simulation but not on the device? Or are you receiving a synthesis error?

Answer (score 1):

Some coding feedback first of all.  Don't mix blocking and non-blocking assignments. You can totally do it, but things can get confusing.  In you case, you have `counter` assigned as non-blocking (<=) and then as blocking (=).  I am guessing you could get away with everything as blocking.

I'll ask the very simple question up front.  The clock name indicates 1K, which could 1KHz.  How are you "measuring" your outputs to know that they are not working?  At 1K, you might not see lights flash...  Assuming that you have a O-Scope or an LA and have proved it is not working, I'll go through what I would do next.

Check how wide is `counter`?  Is it at least 4 bits wide?  Better be.

Check the following on your board.  If you have an o-scope, check that your input clock is really running.  Next, check your synthesis PIN assignment file.  Make sure you assigned the clock to the right pin on the device.

Next, signal_count is effectively your design reset.  You need to make sure that reset (signal_count) is also assigned to the right pin and actually moving when you push a button or whatever.

Then validate that you are really programming the device correctly.  Is there a `done` pin?  A troublehooting step, do you have someone elses design that does work?   If it works on their board and not yours, that is a bit telling and points to suspect hardware, or a maybe a missing jumper or power supply.

Finally, create a new program.  Make it ultra simple as shown below.
Get that oscope out and show that the working signal oscillates as expected.  This will not simulate as written because the initial state of `working` isn't defined, but on the real board, it should oscillate at half frequency. If it does, you know you have clock.

```
always @ (posedge CLK_1K) 
begin 
    working <= ~working;
end
```

IF IT DOES NOT OSCILLATE, change the program to

```
assign working = 1'b1
```

and verify that the signal goes high when the device loads.  If it doesn't the problem is not with your source, but something more like a bad pin assignment, bad pin, bad supply, etc...

Then alter to the following

```
always @ (posedge CLK_1K) 
begin 
    working <= signal_count ? ~working : 1'b0;
end
```

This will stop the oscillation proving your signal count is operating.

Respond with the results of this testing and we will go from there.